# WaterlineJS find all not in ($nin)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, orm, sails.js, waterline

I'm using the Waterline ORM (MongoDB adapter) with SailsJS and trying to return all documents that don't match the specified query along the lines of this:

```
    User.find({
        id: { $nin: [array] }
    }).done(...)
```

I understand that when passing in an array it will automatically query with the $in operator, but how can I query with the $nin operator?

Comment: it should be absolutely the same. (Or at least the syntax in mongo is the same)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the same. I've tried using the same syntax as in mongodb. For example, to use the $in operator in Waterline you just simply pass in the array and don't need to specify the $in operator.

Comment: Another reason not to use some weird adapters/frameworks/tools for things that can be easily solved without them. Especially if they are not properly documented.

Answer (score 1):

Currently works in the master branch of sails-mongo.

```
User.find({
    id: { '!': [array] }
}).exec(/* ... */)
```

In Waterline `IN` queries are done with an array of values. The query language works the same in all the adapters.

You can read more on the [Waterline-Docs](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/query-language.md)